# Set Hex Value using prepeared stmt in java

Tags: sql, db2

I have a statement below:

```
insert into t1 (col1) values (x'4D7953514C');
```

I want to insert this value into a DB2 database table using a prepared statement:

```
insert into t1 (col1) values (?);
```

If I use string and the data type `NCHAR` I get an exception:

```
 com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: Unrecognized jdbc type -15
```

How can I achieve this ?

UPDATE:

```
String SQL = "insert into t1 (col1) values (?);"
String id = "x'"+id+"'";  // here id = 20151120120811356186000000

Object args[] = { id};

int types[] = { Types.CHAR};

db2Template.update(SQL, args, types);
```

Comment: Tried CHAR instead of NCHAR?

Comment: tried it already but no luck .

Comment: if i use CHAR , it throws 'Illegal conversion' Exception

Comment: Does you char variable simply contain 4D7953514C only?

Comment: i am updating my code ..pls check above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x'4D7953514C'` is not a "hex string"; it is a binary string, which corresponds to the DB2 data type `VARCHAR(whatever_length) FOR BIT DATA` (or may be `CHAR(whatever_length) FOR BIT DATA`).

The respective Java data type is `byte[]`, so you'll need to do something like

```
byte[] x = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x15, ..., 0x00};
...
int types[] = {Types.WHATEVER_CORRESPONDS_TO_THE_ACTUAL_DB2_TYPE};
...
```

Comment: that is correct..thanx a lot.one more thing do u have any idea about batch update in db2 how it works..actually when i am trying it using jdbctemplate its throwing an exception .'com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.rg: Non-atomic batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch. Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements.' any Idea ?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it as another question.